# PhpStorm line break on method

Tags: phpstorm

I would like to insert a line break at every object method on auto reformat into PhpStorm :

eg :

```php
function (object $object)
{
    $object->method1()->method2()->method3();

    // select and press ctrl + alt + l

    $object
        ->method1()
        ->method2()
        ->method3()
    ;
}
```

I use already use a `.editorconfig` file but I have no clue to found the right parameter!

Comment: PhpStorm calls it "chained method calls". This is basically the same question: [PHPStorm. Reformat code. Chained method call wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154610/phpstorm-reformat-code-chained-method-call-wrapping). Not sure if the answer solves the problem or applies to current version.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yep You found it ! Thx !